# Any known problems with GlassFish high availability?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, weblogic

From the GlassFish Server release notes (4.0 and 4.1):

> Clusters and ... High availability features ...  are included in the release, but they may not function properly...

This is kind of scary since we are releasing a Jave EE app build on glassfish, and are just about to set up a high availability install. It is for big enterprises.

Do you know about any known issues that should make us switch to e.g. WebLogic Clusters? We are strongly debating the use of glassfish also because of a lack of commercial support for it.

On the other hand, weblogic does have a support charge from Oracle, which brings up the question: what benefits would we be getting for our money if we switched? Does it have a more solid high availability offering?

Comment: There are some good notes here about Oracle "leaving" Glassfish: https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/6_facts_about_glassfish_announcement If you think you may EVER need support, it's probably worth switching to Weblogic. That said, I do not believe this is a good question for StackOverflow, as it has very little to do with programming

Comment: If you want a support option, there are other options for support since Oracle stopped theirs, e.g. http://payara.co/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be wise to use the latest release of GlassFish (4.1), [it's mostly a bugfix release](https://java.net/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-printable/temp/SearchRequest.html?jqlQuery=project%20%3D%20GLASSFISH%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%224.1%22%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Resolved%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC&tempMax=1000), but does add the capability to run on Java 8.

As for known issues with high availability, that's something that's easily checked with the public GlassFish JIRA

[Here is a query for any issue which affects versions 4.0 or 4.1 which mentions the word "cluster"](https://java.net/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20GLASSFISH%20AND%20affectedVersion%20in%20(4.0%2C%204.1)%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22cluster%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC)

The Payara project is actively developing GlassFish in parallel with the main project, [so issues on the Github repo](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues) may address some of those in the future.